# Is it possible to load K8S list of services into Helm template variable?

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm

I was looking for a solution but I couldn't find any.

I have a bash script which executes something like this:

```sh
kubectl get services -o=json | \
jq '.items[].metadata.annotations | '\
   'select (."my-ingress/enabled" == "true") | '\
   '{"my-ingress/path", "my-ingress/service-name", "my-ingress/service-port"}'
```

Which means it can take list of the services, filter and take only with annotations `my-ingress/enabled == true`

Based on that result it creates dynamically YAML for Ingress and loads it.

Everywhere I was looking, Helm is using templates and other fancy approaches but nowhere I could find any information how to ask K8S about some resources and based on that info build YAML.

Is this possible at all?

***Note***: calling Bash to prepare some kind `values.yaml` is not an option in my case.

Comment: out of interest, seeing that you are aware of helm existing and can easily deploy ingress when `.Values.ingress.enabled`, how do you deploy the services now?

Comment: That sounds like you might be looking for a Kubernetes [Controller](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/architecture/controller/), a program that uses the [Kubernetes API](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/overview/kubernetes-api/) to monitor Service objects with some annotation and create Ingress objects.  Helm isn't great at this sort of extremely dynamic task.

Comment: A more typical pattern for Helm would be a chart for a single application that creates a Service with a known name, and creates the corresponding Ingress.  Within the context of the Helm chart it knows which Service(s) it installs and is able to construct the Ingress object without actually inspecting what exists in the cluster.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may use [HELM's lookup function](https://helm.sh/docs/chart_template_guide/functions_and_pipelines/#using-the-lookup-function) to query the cluster

> The lookup function can be used to look up resources in a running
> cluster. The synopsis of the lookup function is lookup apiVersion,
> kind, namespace, name -> resource or resource list.
>
> parameter type apiVersion string kind string namespace    string
> name  string Both name and namespace are optional and can be passed as
> an empty string ("").

```
{{ range $index, $service := (lookup "v1" "Service" "mynamespace" "").items }}
    {{/* do something with each service */}}
{{ end }}
```

**Important note:**

> Keep in mind that Helm is not supposed to contact the Kubernetes API Server during a `helm template` or a `helm install|update|delete|rollback --dry-run`, so the lookup function will return an empty list (i.e. dict) in such a case.

Comment: This would be the way. You can iterate the services and check them with an if/else condition.